# How to open watch view using IDAPython?

Tags: idapython

I want to open the watch view and add watch in code. Do you know how? I didn't find open_window_ for it. I couldn't understand which function to use with `BWN_...` or `IWID_...` constants ( `IWID_WATCH` seems like watch view).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, `idaapi.process_ui_action('WatchView')`